# error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in binding

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#

I just started working on F# and tried running a basic program but the output is coming out to be wrong.

Earlier it was showing error "error FS0010: Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in binding" but right now it's just showing ;; on terminal. I am running the code real-time using **FSI: Send line**.

Code: ->

```
let prep prefixStr baseStr = 
   prefixStr + ", " + baseStr

prep "Hello" "Mohit"
```

Comment: your code itself is correct. `> val prep : prefixStr:string -> baseStr:string -> string
val it : string = "Hello, Mohit"` Just select the whole region and send it with Alt+Enter. What is the editor you're using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using F# Interactive, you need to send it complete valid blocks of F# code. A single line (function header) that is followed by the body is not a valid block. If you send the first line of your code, the editor sees:

```
let prep prefixStr baseStr =
```

It complains because this is incomplete. Better way of working is to highlight the whole function definition and then use **FSI: Send Selection** with selection being:

```
let prep prefixStr baseStr = 
   prefixStr + ", " + baseStr
```

This will define the function. After that, you can run the last line using either **FSI: Send Selection** or using **FSI: Send Line** because this is a stand-alone valid expression:

```
prep "Hello" "Mohit"
```